# Model3D property in PowerPoint not showing up in list of references

Tags: c#, vb.net, office365, powerpoint

I need to create a script that validates whether or not the correct view was applied to a 3D model, but the application I am writing the script for does not recognize the Model3DFormat object or the Model3D property under the property ShapeRange that I need to perform this validation.

The version of PowerPoint the application uses acknowledges that 3D models exist, as the 3D models are on the slides in the files used by the application and the Model3D property appears in the Developer tab, but it just seems to be the VBA script validation that doesn't recognize 3D models.

I have tried updating the NuGet packages (latest version showing for Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint is 15.0.4420.1017, which I have installed to the application) and removing and re-adding the PowerPoint Object library in the references list, but neither seem to have changed anything.

Here is the script I am trying to get working:

```
Try
Dim rcount As Integer
With Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(3).Model3D
   If .RotationX = 90 And _
            .RotationY = 300 And _
            .RotationZ = 270 Then
                Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
End With

Catch ex As Exception
   Return False
End Try
```

[Image of the Solution Explorer for the application showing the reference list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2DMt.png)

Comment: Please clarify. You mention NuGet, which implies VB or C# in Visual Studio, since NuGet packages are not usable in the VBA editor. Please post your code.

Comment: It's a .NET program that uses VB scripts to check that certain changes were made in MS Office, while the rest of the program is coded in C#.  I've written a VB script that works in my local PowerPoint application, but the library for the application doesn't seem to include the Model3D property like the local environment, and I'm not sure how to update the dll to have it in there.

Comment: OK, so not VBA at all. I've edited your tags. Please post your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Code of the script I am trying to get working has been added to the original question.